# LastPage to be set on specific page

Tags: lastpage, pageref

I have a very specific issue with the LastPage Package. I'll try and explain the best I can.

So I have an article. That uses:

```
\rfoot {Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

To add the page number to the bottom of each page. which works fine.

But I would like my "Last Page" To be my references page. My basic article structure is.

- Title
- Fore Pages (Nomenclature, Abstract, Table of Contents)
- Main Body (Introduction, ETC ETC References)
- Aft Pages (Glossary, Index, Appendix)

Is there any way to set the Reference Page as the Last page so all pages above that are correct e.g Page 1 of 3. I don't want the Glossary, Index, Appendix included in the page count.

For my References Page I'm using:

```
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}
```

Any help would be greatly appricated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the beginning of the Reference section as the last page, you can add a label immediately after `\newpage`, say `\newpage\label{mylastpage}`, and use that label in `\pageref{mylastpage}`.

If you want to use the end of the Reference section as the last page, add the label after `\bibliography{referencec}`.

With this you don't even need the `LastPage` package.

Comment: Awesome worked a treat. Thank you. One thing though \label{mylastpage} didn't work i had to use \label{myLastPage}. No idea why I also removed the last page package.

Comment: You don't need it.  (Do you have any idea how many problems result from loading unused packages, usually the result of a "template"?)

Comment: Honestly no I do not. I'm newish to TeX but this article that I'm writing I built from a blank template. I was using the LastPage package but it wasn't fit for my needs. But Herr K. solution worked a treat.